# Cards Stack swipe - add card in the back after swiping (removing) top card

Tags: android-recyclerview, swipe

I use this library: https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView. It's like **Tinder-like swiping** cards left-right and it's based on RecyclerView.

This library has the following settings: `cardStackLayoutManager.setVisibleCount(3)` - that means that the number of visible cards at any time is MAXed to 3 cards.

Suppose I have an array with 5 elements, and then I load everything to my adapter.

On the screen, I'll see 3 cards - holding the first three elements from the array.

**The Problem** is that when I swipe the top card, (deleting it from the stack), then I have two cards left, **but I'm expecting a new card appear at the bottom** with the 4th element from the array, but it never happens unless I remove the first element from an array and then call: `notifyDataSetChanged()` which reloads the entire stack, adapter (and it comes up with blinking, flashing, etc.)

All I need is to load the NEXT element from the array in the new card at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. First, in Adapter, since I'm dealing with only 3 preloaded cards in stock at any time, I do this:

```
int countCards;

SwipeAdapter(ArrayList<String> userIDArr, Context ctx)
{
    this.userIDArr2      = userIDArr;
    .......

    if (userIDArr2.size() >= 3) {
        countCards = 3;
    } else {
        countCards = userIDArr2.size();
    }
    .......

    this.ctx        = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return countCards;
}
```

... that's provided that the total array `userIDArr.size()` might be more than 3 but `getItemCount` can only be MAX 3 or less (if the array size is less than 3).

Then, in an Activity that deals with an adapter, when I swipe the card whichever way, I remove index 0 (top card) from the array and then call `notifyItemRemoved`:

```
userIDArr.remove(0);

if (userIDArr.size() > 2) {
    swipeAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(0);
}
```

**NOTICE** that `notifyItemRemoved` is only called when **the array still has 3 or more** items left.

Works perfectly smooth.